# Getting error while using generic generator

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, h2

Using Spring Boot 2.1.1 with H2 database testing JPA.

Error

**There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not set field value [ST30790] value by reflection : [class com.example.demo.model.Student.id] setter of com.example.demo.model.Student.id; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [ST30790] value by reflection : [class com.example.demo.model.Student.id] setter of com.example.demo.model.Student.id**

Student class

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "Student_id")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "Student_id", strategy = "com.example.demo.model.StudentGenerator")
    private int id;
    private String email;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

My generator

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Random;

public class StudentGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {

    private static final String STUDENT_ID_PREFIX = "ST";

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return STUDENT_ID_PREFIX + String.valueOf(generateID());
    }

    public static char[] generateID() {

        //Creating object of Random class
        Random obj = new Random();

        char[] otp = new char[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            otp[i] = (char) (obj.nextInt(10) + 48);
        }
        System.out.print("Your OTP is : " + otp.toString());
        return otp;
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Could you try to replace `int` by `Integer`?

Comment: @SternK did that nothing worked!

Comment: Could you please show your hibernate config and what H2 version do you use?

Comment: I am using spring boot. here is the properties of database.

       spring.h2.console.enabled=true
       spring.datasource.platform=h2
       spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:admin

Answer (score 1):

Your generator output are strings, however your student entity id is int. Change `int` to `string` in Student `id` attribute and it should work.

Comment: I tried this earlier it works also. Unfortunately, gives an error

     There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Optional int parameter 'id' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.

Comment: I also tried initializing value of id through constructor so it doesn't show it as null but it didn't work, getting same error

Comment: @MindFlayerA, The pepevalbe's advice works fine. See the worked example [here](https://github.com/KostjaStern/TestSpringBoot).